# return the first non-zero value of the array XSLT

Tags: arrays, xslt

I have an array

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$item//property[@name='bla2']/value" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="$item//property[@name='bla1']/value" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="%item//property[@name='bla']/value" />
```

I need to output (return) the first non-zero value. How do I do it?

Comment: You need to add several things to your post: an XML input, more of your (if not the entire) stylesheet and the XML output you expect. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample request xml of yours too in your question?

Comment: Do you mean "first non-zero" or "first non-empty" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="($item//property[@name='bla2']/value | $item//property[@name='bla1']/value | $item//property[@name='bla']/value)[not (. = 0)][1]" />
```

but I am guessing. I agree with the comments, show us the XML you have, the XSLT you have, the result you want and the one you get, then we can suggest how to adapt the code.